# How to check out a SVN directory?

Tags: svn, svn-checkout

I checked out my application regularly on my terminal by using this code:

```
sudo svn export https://svn.domain.com/svn/repos-myapp/trunk/Application /var/www/versions/stage/temp
```

Since last week, I get the following error:

```
svn: PROPFIND request failed on '/svn/repos-myapp/trunk/Application'
svn: PROPFIND of '/svn/repos-myapp/trunk/Application': 405 Method Not Allowed (http://svn.domain.com)
```

Unfortunately, I don't know why it happens. Does anyone have an idea? When googling the problem, I only find apache/permission solutions which I can't influence because the SVN server is not hosted by myself.. But the host tells me that nothing has changed since 2 month..

Answer (score 0):

Did you go through the possible reasons described in the [FAQ](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#four05)?

Comment: I am not using tortoisesvn. Cheers

Comment: That particular section of the FAQ is not specific to TortoiseSVN.

Comment: Point 1 + 2 are TSVN related and Nr. 3 is not possible because I did not change anything on the infrastructure as described in the question. Point 4 is a different error. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done a svn verify?

http://durak.org/sean/pubs/software/version-control-with-subversion-1.6/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.verify.html

Also, there may be other causes for a 405, other than server permissions. Has anything changed on your end. Firewall/proxy perhaps?

http://vsingleton.blogspot.com/2008/04/svn-propfind-request-failed-on.html